# CSS inline/block issue

Tags: html, css, inline, block

I am having trouble with css inline/block when using a `<span>` tag.[image]

[image]

As you can see from the images, when you hover over the third message the Delete/Reply controls pop up, I do not wish for them to push the content down. How can I accomplish this?

This is my css code:

```
ul.inbox {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.unread {
    border: 1px solid #999 !important;
    background: #eee url("new.png") no-repeat !important;
    background-position: left center !important;
}

li span.hidden {
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

li span.messageControls {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}

li span.messageControls a {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #06c;
}

li.message {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-position: left center;
}

li.message:hover {

}

li.message a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    overflow: hidden;
}

li span.from {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    font-family:"Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 700;
}

li span.date {
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
    color: #06c;
}

li p.subject {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 700;
}

li p.preview {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
}
```

And my 'inbox' code:

```
<ul class="inbox">
    <li id="1001843" class="message " onmouseout="document.getElementById('1001843MC').className='hidden'" onmouseover="document.getElementById('1001843MC').className='messageControls'" onclick="ajaxMessage(1001843);">
        <span class="from">Michael‌·Norris</span> <span class="date">Yesterday‌·21:18</span> <span id="1001843MC" class="hidden"><a href="compose.php?id=&to=">Reply</a> &nbsp; <a href="update.php?id=&action">Delete</a></span>

        <p class="subject">gjhgjhg</p>

        <p class="preview">jhgjhgjhg</p>
    </li>

    <li id="1001842" class="message " onmouseout="document.getElementById('1001842MC').className='hidden'" onmouseover="document.getElementById('1001842MC').className='messageControls'" onclick="ajaxMessage(1001842);">
        <span class="from">Michael‌·Norris</span> <span class="date">Yesterday‌·21:18</span> <span id="1001842MC" class="hidden"><a href="compose.php?id=&to=">Reply</a> &nbsp; <a href="update.php?id=&action">Delete</a></span>

        <p class="subject">gfhjgjfdhsgf</p>

        <p class="preview">gj‌·hg</p>
    </li>

    <li id="1001841" class="message " onmouseout="document.getElementById('1001841MC').className='hidden'" onmouseover="document.getElementById('1001841MC').className='messageControls'" onclick="ajaxMessage(1001841);">
        <span class="from">Michael‌·Norris</span> <span class="date">Yesterday‌·20:17</span> <span id="1001841MC" class="hidden"><a href="compose.php?id=&to=">Reply</a> &nbsp; <a href="update.php?id=&action">Delete</a></span>

        <p class="subject">gjhgjhg</p>

        <p class="preview">jhgjhgjhg</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Er73L/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `clear` properties correctly to achieve the behavior you want, and not just use `clear: both` blindly.

I did two changes to your CSS:

```
li span.messageControls {
    clear: right; /* was clear: both; */
    float: right;
    display: block; /* was display: inline */
}

li p.subject {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    clear: left; /* was clear: both; */
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Er73L/2/). I also recommend you read up on the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control).

Comment: No problem. `inline`s don't float, thats why Pennywise doesn't like them.

Comment: @MartínValdésdeLeón In fact, inlines [become block](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/displaypositionfloat) when they are floated, so when you float something, there is not much sense in setting `display: inline` or `display: block` anyways. In fact, you have `display: inline` in your fiddle, which works just fine :).

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I will be sure to remember that. So just to recap, by clearing just the left hand side, you can still float stuff to the right of it on the same line so to speak?

Comment: Yes, I know that float turns inlines into blocks and that the css was working without that change, but I think the result ends up being misleading so its better to remove that line. And Mike, you are correct. The `clear` property specifies that nothing can float on that side of the element, but still allows you to float stuff to the other side of the element (unless of course you `clear: both`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I propose you fix this: http://jsfiddle.net/Er73L/1/

Here's the diff compared to your original CSS: http://www.diffchecker.com/3tKbEnCe

```
li span.messageControls {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 1em;
}

li.message {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-position: left center;
    position: relative;  // NEW LINE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix, just use `clear:left` instead of `clear:both` like this:

```
li p.subject {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    clear:left;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Er73L/6/)

Answer (score 0):

another option is to absolutely position the span elements,. just add this line to the bottom of your css and tweak it as needed...

```
.messageControls{width:100px;border:1px solid red;position:absolute;right:0;margin-top:20px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nYCsx/1/

Comment: They will all appear at the top right corner of the document.

Comment: Show us the test then. jsFiddle, pastebin, etc., that's how people do it here.

Comment: I havent used jsFiddle that much so hope this link works... http://jsfiddle.net/nYCsx/1/

I used the code from the question, and only added the line I suggested..

Comment: OK, I get it now. `position: relative` on the container would have been easier, but I understand now why your solution works :).